# Custom margins in console printing C#

Tags: c#, formatting

How can I format my string to have custom margins for columns, so it would like like below?
I know that "\t" puts a tab into a string but the width is fixed, and I would like to have a possibility of custom columns width

```
By extensions:
                    [count]   [total size]   [avg size]   [min size]   [max size]
    jpg              10        21.5MB         45KB         30KB         230KB
    png              1         1.5MB          1.5MB        1.5MB        1.5MB
    gif              13        4.5MB          ...          ...          ...
    doc              1         120KB          ...          ...          ...
    txt              5         5KB            ...          ...          ...
    mp3              30        96MB           ...          ...          ...
    [other]          0         0B             ...          ...          ...

By sizes:
                    [count]   [total size]   [avg size]   [min size]   [max size]
          . <= 1KB   10        21.5MB         ...          ...          ...
    1KB < . <= 1MB   1         1.5MB          ...          ...          ...
    1MB < . <= 1GB   13        4.5MB          ...          ...          ...
    1GB < .          ...       ...            ...          ...          ...

Counts by first leter:
    A   C   R   ...
    5   3   1   ...

Ordered by name:
                    [size]           [path]
    aaa.png          1.5MB
    bbb.jpg          30KB
    ccc.mp3          2.3MB
    ...

Ordered by sizes (from biggest):
                    [size]
    ccc.mp3          2.3MB
    aaa.png          1.5MB
    bbb.jpg          30KB
    ...
```

Comment: String formatting supports alignment of columns. See this section and the following 2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#control-formatting

Comment: Are you just doing this by `Console.WriteLine($"{extension:format} etc"?  Can we see what your code looks like?

Comment: @Flydog57 This is not printed by my code, it's just an example of how the console outcome should look that I received from my professor. I wrote everything using "\t" and I noticed that it looks different, the width is bigger sometimes and width is fixed. And in the example, some margins are smaller than the others. I wasn't sure if he was just simply using spaces, or some other formatting.

Comment: But, if you _"wrote everything ..."_, then you have code. You should show it. You keep talking about printing; that traditionally means rendering something to paper (or perhaps a digital analog like a PDF file), but I'm guessing you mean writing to a console. With your code, we could tell

Comment: @Flydog57 yup I mean printing to a console. Code:
https://gist.github.com/defcon1one1/c3ca7dee07383c981172e8541be9a956

Comment: Check the [help] out and read up how to prepare a [mcve]. Your code show be pasted into your question